# Вывод изображений из плагина Pods WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У меня установлен плагин Pods. С помощью него зарегистрировала новый тип записи и там добавила кастомное поле с возможностью загружать галерею картинок. Вывожу следующим образом, но картинки не выводятся и не могу понять почему. Появляется только надпись:

Notice: 
/wp-content/themes/gazperspective/template-parts/gallery-slider.php

Буду благодарна за любую подсказку, возможно есть лучше варианты сделать множественную загрузку изображений(нужно для slick-слайдера).

```php
<?php if(have_posts()){ while (have_posts()) {the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'images', false ) ){ //images название вашего произвольного поля
        $image_array = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'images', false ); //images название вашего произвольного поля
    }
    if ( $image_array ) {
        foreach ( $image_array as $image ) {
        $fullimg = pods_image_url( $image['ID'], 'large');
        echo '<div class="gallery-slider__item"><img src="'.  $fullimg . '"></div>';
        }
    } ?>
<?php } /* конец while */?>
<?php } /* конец if */?>
```

Comment: Возле нотиса должна быть еще какая-то информация в которой и написана вся проблема

Comment: @Krya спасибо, уже решила проблему. невнимательная просто, нужно было выводить через цикл wp_query. Вдруг кому будет полезно